# How to create unique ID's for each button in a loop using php echo

Tags: php, jquery

I am Having a problem with the button Id id="option_0_0 ,id="option_0_1 and id="option_0_2

Since Now i'm Using echo php, i'm limited to the id's i can give each button to make each button unique,and the loop keeps repeating the id name on each button, how do create unique ID's for each button?

```
<div class="cart">

  <div class="title">Bet Slip</div>
  
  <div id="box" class="boxlit"></div>

  <div>Net Win N$</div>

  <b type="number">300</b>

  <output name="NetWin" for="a b"></output>

  <input type="number" max="100" width="10px">

  <button class="bet1">Bet</button><br />

</div>



<br>

<table id="Table1" class="Fixtures-Table">
    
    <thead>

        <tr>
            
            <th>League</th>
            <th>Home</th>
            <th>Draw</th>
            <th>Away</th>
            <th>Kickoff</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>



    <tbody >

        <tr><th>AFF Women's Championship Group Stage<td id="label" >1<td id="label" >x<td id="label" >2</th></tr>
<tr>
            
                <td class="addItem">Philippines - Australia</td> 
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_0" value ="20.00" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_1" value ="8.75" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_2" value ="1.04" /></td>
                <td class="label">7/4/2022 13:00</td> 
                
            </tr><tr><th>Africa Women Cup of Nations<td id="label" >1<td id="label" >x<td id="label" >2</th></tr>
<tr>
            
                <td class="addItem">Nigeria - South Africa</td> 
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_0" value ="2.00" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_1" value ="3.05" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_2" value ="3.45" /></td>
                <td class="label">7/4/2022 19:00</td> 
                
            </tr><tr>
            
                <td class="addItem">Burundi - Botswana</td> 
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_0" value ="3.65" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_1" value ="3.10" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_2" value ="1.95" /></td>
                <td class="label">7/4/2022 22:00</td> 
                
            </tr><tr><th>Argentina Liga Profesional Argentina<td id="label" >1<td id="label" >x<td id="label" >2</th></tr>
<tr>
```

this loop is generated from php echo like this

```
            echo  

            '<tr>
            
                <td class="addItem">'. $row["COL 2"] .'</td> 
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_0" value ="'. $row["COL 3"] .'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_1" value ="'. $row["COL 4"] .'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option_0_2" value ="'. $row["COL 5"] .'" /></td>
                <td class="label">'. $row["COL 6"] .'</td> 
                
            </tr>';
        
        }
        
    
        ?>
```

Comment: why you added jQuery in the tags?

Comment: Excuse me? which tag exactly?

Comment: The tags of the _question_ you asked.

Comment: Use a loop counter variable, and append the value of that in the relevant places. (If these IDs are actually _necessary_ to begin with, often there are other ways to access the relevant elements, based on context.)

Comment: Consider:  You don't need a dynamic `id=` on your inputs; you *probably* don't need an id at all.   Consider what you're using it for and if there's an alternatively, such as using `data-option-group='0' data-question-index='1'` instead of `option_0_1` etc.

Comment: how do I insert data-option-group='0' data-question-index='1' into my input, its giving me red lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking how to change the id with jquery ? If so then this should do that for you

```
$(".decimals").each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr("id", index);
});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing from your PHP code, therefore I assume that you need the solution in PHP code. If so, here you go:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($rows as $row) {

echo
    '<tr>'.
    '<td class="addItem">'. $row["COL 2"] .'</td>'.
    '<td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option' . $i++ . '" value ="'. $row["COL 3"] .'" /></td>'.
    '<td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option' . $i++ . '" value ="'. $row["COL 4"] .'" /></td>'.
    '<td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="option' . $i++ . '" value ="'. $row["COL 5"] .'" /></td>'.
    '<td class="label">'. $row["COL 6"] .'</td>'.
    '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.